# How to get a property from an observablelist with multiple properties

Tags: java, javafx

```
private final ObservableList<City> cityList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(city
        -> new Observable[]{
            city.cityNameProperty(),
            city.cityLonProperty(),
            city.cityLatProperty()});

public ObservableList<City> getCityList() {
    return cityList;
}
```

How can I retrieve the cityNameProperty from one object inside the observableArrayList for setting a listview?

I did

```
cityView.setItems(cityList.getCityList());
```

But this is setting the objects (city@59f..etc), whereas I need the properties of the objects.

Comment: @Mena I only need one property (cityNameProperty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cell factory:

```
cityView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<City>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(City city, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(city, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : city.getCityName());
    }
});
```